# Bring to forward window when minimized

Tags: c#, window, foreground

I want to know how to bring forward a particular window.
SetForegroundWindow works when the window is not minimized!! but when a minimize the window, SetForegroundWindow doesn't work...

this my code:

```
        int IdRemoto = int.Parse(textBoxID.Text);

        Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcessesByName("AA_v3.3");

        foreach (Process process in processlist)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
            {
                if (IdRemoto.ToString() == process.MainWindowTitle)
                    SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);  
            }
        }


[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Answer (score 15):

You can check to see if the window is minimized using the [IsIconic()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isiconic) API, then use [ShowWindow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) to restore it:

```
public const int SW_RESTORE = 9;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr handle);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr handle, int nCmdShow);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr handle);

private void BringToForeground(IntPtr extHandle)
{
    if (IsIconic(extHandle))
    {
        ShowWindow(extHandle, SW_RESTORE);
    }
    SetForegroundWindow(extHandle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) combined with what you already have, here is your example with a little modification:

```
    int IdRemoto = int.Parse(textBoxID.Text);

    Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcessesByName("AA_v3.3");

    foreach (Process process in processlist)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
        {
            if (IdRemoto.ToString() == process.MainWindowTitle)
            {
                ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, 9);
                SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);  
            }
        }
    }


   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWind, int nCmdShow);
```