# VB - How to restore a minimized Notepad from the taskbar

Tags: vb.net, taskbar

I have used StackOverFLow a few times to steal snippets.  This time I have a question since my thievery skills seem to have diminished.  I'm using VB.NET.

I have a NoteButton in MyApp.  The first time NoteButton is clicked Notepad starts with a particular text file.
On subsequent clicks of NoteButton - if NotePad and the file are open then activate Notepad.

If NotePad has been minimized how do I change the WindowState / AppWinstyle to "normal" and bring it to the foreground?

Here is what I have...

---

```
    On Error GoTo EHandler
    Dim TheDirectory = MyApp.My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
    If IsRunningExe("notepad.exe") Then  'Check if notepad is already running
        On Error Resume Next
        AppActivate("MyList.txt - Notepad")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear()
            Process.Start("notepad.exe", TheDirectory & "\MyList.txt")
        End If
                    'I need to restore a minimized Notepad to "Normal" state and in the foreground 
                     here.
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Process.Start("notepad.exe", TheDirectory & "\MyList.txt")
    Exit Sub
    EHandler:
    MsgBox("There was an error opening the text file.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation)
```

---

Thanks for your time,

Greg

Comment: Google "vb.net ui automation restore window".  [Sample hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315561/correct-way-in-net-to-switch-the-focus-to-another-application).

Comment: This SO question should be able to help you out: [Restore a minimized window of another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099479/restore-a-minimized-window-of-another-application). It's in C# but you should be able translate it easy enough

Comment: You can use [IsIconic()...example here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19863085/2330053)

Comment: In .net, please don't use `On Error GoTo...`. We have Exception and `Try...Catch...Finally...End Try`

Comment: Thanks to all for the help.  I did get it working but to avoid any embarrassment on my side - I won't post my code here.  Mary - I learned VBA when the Excel 4.0 macro language was abandoned and I was forced to port my add-in app over from the macro language to VBA.  It wasn't easy.  That was in about 1996.  My first dip into vb.Net is this app.  It does what I need and want (it talks to my 3D printer).  It's good enough and nobody else will have to come behind me and straighten out my spaghetti.